# parsing json object with number as its key fields?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I'm trying to parse json into kotlin objects but the problem is that its key fields are numbers any idea how can parse them , I've tried serialized name but still facing problem.

The json response looks like this :

```
{
    "Id": [{
            "1": {
                "name": "name1",
                "class": "11a"
            }
        },
        {
            "2": {
                "name": "name2",
                "class": "11b"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using gson and the main thing i'm trying to do is to store this number fields as some other string objects.

Comment: What you posted wasn't valid JSON. Changed it to Valid JSON, while still keeping your question the way it is, since it's still a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse them into a list of maps, then "map" those to your data classes instead:

```
    val input = """{
    "Id": [{
            "1": {
                "name": "name1",
                "class": "11a"
            }
        },
        {
            "2": {
                "name": "name2",
                "class": "11b"
            }
        }
    ]
}"""

    val gson = Gson()
    val parsed: Map<String, List<Map<String, Any>>> = 
        gson.fromJson(input, (object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<Map<String, Any>>>>(){}).type)
    println(parsed["Id"]?.get(0)?.get("1")) // {name=name1, class=11a}
```

It will have some nasty generic signature, though.

If you're working with Kotlin, take a look at [Klaxon](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon), it will improve your experience.

Comment: There's no `countryitems` in the JSON you've provided, so my example may not work as-is on your code. Are you getting the error while parsing or while fetching values?

Comment: `val parsed: Map<String, List<Map<String, Any>>> =
                    gson.fromJson(body, (object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<Map<String, Any>>>>(){}).type)
                                                                                                   val parsedvalue: Map<Any, Any> = parsed["id"]?.get(0)?.get("1) as Map<Any, Any>`

Comment: thanks this fixed my problem I mapped the data further by storing it into another variable.    val parsedvalue in this example.